# Flutter Notification Sound for IOS Apps

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I want to set custom sound to notification in my application which using firebase notification.
In android worked perfectly, but in IOS not working. I put audio file in ios/runner, but notification received silently.

Comment: Check [this](https://medium.com/@dmennis/the-3-ps-to-custom-alert-sounds-in-ios-push-notifications-9ea2a2956c11). Also Note that the sound duration must be <30 sec

Comment: the sound just  5 sec, but not working

Comment: check the provided link , that might help